# using %in% to subset a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(4,4,4,4), x=c(1,3,5,5))
> DT
   a b x
1: 1 4 1
2: 2 4 3
3: 3 4 5
4: 4 4 5
```

and I would like to select rows where `x` equals either `a` or `b`. Obviously, I could use

```
> DT[x==a | x==b]
   a b x
1: 1 4 1
```

which gives the correct result. However, with many columns I thought, the follwoing should work just as well

```
> DT[x%in%c(a,b)]
   a b x
1: 1 4 1
2: 2 4 3
```

but it gives a different result that is not intuitive to me. Can anyone help?

Comment: `c(a,b)` is essentially combining those two vectors: the `a` column in `DT` and the `b` column in DT, which is `1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```r
 DT[x==a | x==b]
```

returns all rows in `DT` where the values in `x` and `a` are equal or `x` and `b` are equal. This is the desired result.

On the other hand

```r
 DT[x%in%c(a,b)]
```

returns all rows where `x` matches *any* value in `c(a, b)`, not just the corresponding value. Thus your second row appears because `x == 3` and `3` appears (somewhere) in `a`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Reduce` with `.SDcols` for multiple columns.  Specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, then loop over the `.SD` (Subset of Data.table), do the comparison (`==`) with 'x', and `Reduce` it to a single logical vector with `|`

```
DT[DT[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `==`, x)), .SDcols = a:b]]
#   a b x
#1: 1 4 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is use `rowSums`

```
DT[rowSums(DT[,.SD,.SDcols=-'x']==x)>0,]
#   a b x
#1: 1 4 1
```

You can change to `rowMeans...==1` if you want to select rows where all columns equal `x`